# If checked statement jquery primefaces

Tags: jquery, if-statement, primefaces, radio-button

I know there are some topics on this already but I think I have the right concepts just a flaw somewhere. I need a if statement that determines if the radioButton is checked. Below is my code.

```
if($j("input:radio[name=selector1]").is(":checked")){
   //do something here
}


<p:selectOneRadio id="radioButtonsId" widgetVar="rb1">

    <f:selectItem id="selector1" itemLabel="Yes" itemValue="true"/>
    <f:selectItem id="selector2" itemLabel="No" itemValue="false"/>

</p:selectOneRadio>
```

I'm wondering if the name in the if block is wrong. I've also had alot of problems with primeFaces and jQuery together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why this won't work is because of the selector `input:radio[name=selector1]`. The id *selector1* will not be the *id* nor the *name* of the input tag. The *id* and *name* of the input tags for the radio buttons group will follow the naming conventions:

*id*: `formId:selectOneRadioId:indexOfTagInGroup`

*name*: `formId:selectOneRadioId`

So in your case, the name of *selector1* will be `someGeneratedJSFId:radioButtonsId` and the *id* will be `someGeneratedJSFId:radioButtonsId:0`. In order to select this particular element, you could use:

```
 $("input:radio[id*=radioButtonsId\\:0]")
```

- `id*=` selects the radio buttons that have an *id* that contains the String that you specify
- `\\` is the escape character for meta-characters like `:`
- `0` selects the first input tag in the radio buttons group

So, try the following instead:

```
 if($("input:radio[id*=radioButtonsId\\:0]").is(":checked")){
    //do something here
 }

<p:selectOneRadio id="radioButtonsId" widgetVar="rb1">
     <f:selectItem id="selector1" itemLabel="Yes" itemValue="true"/>
     <f:selectItem id="selector2" itemLabel="No" itemValue="false"/>
</p:selectOneRadio>
```